# デバッグビルドしたＡＰＫをＡｎｄｒｏｉｄ端末にインストールすると、１件しかインストールできない

Tags: android, monaca

デバッグビルドしたＡＰＫをＡｎｄｒｏｉｄ端末にインストールすると、１件しかインストールできません。複数のＡＰＫを端末にインストールできるようにするにはどうすればいいのか教えてください。

Answer (score 5):

同一のアプリケーションは1バージョンのみ存在可能です。
ここで"同一"というのは、アプリケーションパッケージ名が同じである、ということです。

逆に言えば、アプリケーションパッケージ名を変えれば併存させることが可能です(正確には、別アプリだと認識させる、ということになりますが)。
これは、`AndroidManifest.xml` 内の`<manifest>` エレメント `package` 属性

```
<manifest package="com.example.project" . . . >
```

を変えることで実現します。

参考: http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#package

> The package name defines your application's identity, so if you change it, then it is considered to be a different application

このとき、アクティビティやサービスクラスの名前を[簡素化](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#filec)表記している場合は、追加でFQCN表記に修正する作業も発生することに留意してください。

---

Android開発における一般的な説明は上記のとおりですが、Monaca的にはメニューから選択できる設定ページで設定するのが行儀が良さそうです。

[image: Monaca IDE]

1. 設定 > Androidアプリ設定... を選択する
2. 表示された「ビルド設定」ウィンドウで、「Androidアプリ」を選択する
3. 「Androidアプリ設定」内の「パッケージ名」を変更し、保存する

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
しかしながら、２つのアプリのpackage名を別々にしたところ、やはりどちから一方しかインストールできません。メッセージも「アプリはインストールされていません」と出るだけです。
よろしくご教授ください。